# float: right; messes up the vertical alignment of elements in HTML

Tags: html, css

I was trying to align these two vector images (instagram and mail) to the right of the div using CSS.

[image]

main.css:

```
.vector{
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
}
```

index.html:

```
<head>
      <div class="container-fluid p-2 bg-primary text-white">
        <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="../public/img/alazkanat2.png"></a>
        <a><img class="vector" src="../public/img/instagram.png"></a>
        <a><img class="vector" src="../public/img/mail.png"></a>
      </div>
</head>
```

I tried to align using (in main.css) by adding `float: right;`:

```
.vector{
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    float: right;
}
```

Resulted with:

[image]

I've tried couple of methods however some didn't even affect the images and some made it worse.
I also tried [Why does the vertical alignment stop working when 'float: right' is being used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56548801/why-does-the-vertical-alignment-stop-working-when-float-right-is-being-used) which is a similar problem to mine but didn't do anything.
(NOTE: Please comment if you need more details from the code)

Comment: Mmm, perhaps a [flex box](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-right-align-flex-item/) could be of use

Comment: @Yarin_007 I tried now it but aligned to the left bottom corner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not tagged, it seems that the posted code is using bootstrap. The below example will use bootstrap classes so that it might integrate better.

Perhaps try use `d-flex` (`display: flex`) on the container with `align-items-center` (`align-items: center`).

Give the first item a `mr-auto` (`margin-right: auto`) so it pushes the other icons to the right.

Example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center container-fluid p-2 bg-primary text-white">
    <a href="#" class="mr-auto"><img class="logo" src="https://picsum.photos/100"></a>
    <a><img class="vector" src="https://picsum.photos/50?random=1"></a>
    <a><img class="vector" src="https://picsum.photos/50?random=2"></a>
  </div>
</header>
```